# How to replace a query string using regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to replace a query string like

`page=3&searchform=1&cityS=-1&category=24&` to `page=[0-9]` ?

I'm using the following

```
preg_replace('/page=d*&?/','',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

but in the end, `&3` appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_replace('/^.*?(\bpage=[0-9]*)&.*$/','$1', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Or else you can simply use

```
$_GET['page']
```

To get this query parameter value.